# How to cast an IDispatch as a TOleServer in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, com, activex, ole

I am attempting to use the Video Capture SDK from

[DTK Software](http://www.dtksoft.com/downloads.php)

in my Delphi App. The only real help they provide, is how to import their type library! I did this succesfully and have a *DTKVideoCapLib_TLB.pas* in my project.

I got this far.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  s: String;
  VideoCaptureUtils: TVideoCaptureUtils;
  VideoDevice: TVideoDevice;
begin
    VideoCaptureUtils := TVideoCaptureUtils.Create(Self);
    for i := 0 to VideoCaptureUtils.VideoDevices.Count - 1 do
    begin
       s := VideoCaptureUtils.VideoDevices.Item[i].Name;
       ShowMessage(s);
       VideoDevice := TVideoDevice(VideoCaptureUtils.Videodevices.Item[i]);
    end;
```

ShowMessage kindly displays me *Microsoft LifeCam VX-800*

so I must have done something right, but after the next line, in the debugger, *VideoDevice* is a `nil`.

Looking over the *DTKVideoCapLib_TLB.pas*, I see the following

```
 TVideoDevice = class(TOleServer)
  private
    FIntf: IVideoDevice;
    function GetDefaultInterface: IVideoDevice;
  protected
  ...

  IVideoDevice = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{8A40EA7D-692C-40EE-9258-6436D1724739}']
    function Get_Name: WideString; safecall;
  ...
```

So now, I really have no idea about how to proceed with this?

**Update**

Corrected item[0] to item[i] in the question. Right-click on item[i] in the IDE and selected Find Declaration takes me to

```
type
  IVideoDeviceCollection = interface(IDispatch) 
    ...
    property Item[index: Integer]: IVideoDevice read Get_Item;
    ...
  end;
```

Comment: Unchecked casts are usually bad. How do you know that `VideoCaptureUtils.Videodevices.Item[0]` really is of type `TVideoDevice`? And why use index `0`? And what type is `VideoCaptureUtils.Videodevices.Item[i]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `as`. Delphi will automatically attempt to obtain the desired interface for you. Something like this (untested!) should work:

```
var
  VideoDevice: IVideoDevice; // note the type of the variable
....
VideoDevice := VideoCaptureUtils.Videodevices.Item[0] as IVideoDevice;
```

Your update, however, provides more detail that weren't present when I wrote my original answer. That update includes code that indicates that `Videodevices` already contains `IVideoDevice`, so you don't need the cast at all - you just need the proper variable declaration:

```
var
  VideoDevice: IVideoDevice; // note the type of the variable
....
VideoDevice := VideoCaptureUtils.Videodevices.Item[i];
```

Comment: That line produces a compiler error: _[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(65): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TVideoDevice' and 'IVideoDevice'_ while this line  `VideoDevice := VideoCaptureUtils.Videodevices.Item[0] as TVideoDevice;` compiles but produces a runtime error "EIntfCastError: Interface not supported"

Comment: Ok, I was also a bit quick in my reply above. Once I changed the VideoDevice type to IVideoDevice, the problem was resolved. I'm marking it as the answer.

Comment: Per David Heffernen's answer below, the cast (as IVideoDevice) is superfluous if the type is IVideoDevice. Do you want to correct your answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
VideoCaptureUtils.Videodevices.Item[i]
```

has type `IVideoDevice`. So you cannot cast it to `TVideoDevice`.

You need to correct the type of the variable:

```
var
  VideoDevice: IVideoDevice;
```

And then assign it like this:

```
VideoDevice := VideoCaptureUtils.VideoDevices.Item[i];
```

Comment: I take it then, that one cannot cast a TVideoDevice as an IVideoDevice either? This explains why the Tx = Class(TOleServer) classes, all have: private... function GetDefaultInterface: Ix methods, right?

Comment: If you really do have a `TVideoDevice` then for sure you can get an `IVideoDevice` from it. But you've got an `IVideoDevice`. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: In terms of the specific question, yes! In terms of using other functionality of the library, no. Mostly I will be using x := Tx.Create(nil); y.Ix := x.GetDefaultInterface, ya see?

Comment: No, I don't think that's the way to do it. Anyway, this question seems to be complete.

Comment: Maybe I should post a new question.

Comment: You accepted an answer here, so I can't see what more can be done here. What's more the answer you accepted here has a needless cast. I can't see why you feel the need for a cast here. It's odd that you do. It seems that you aren't fully on top of it.